# Angular - @angular\cdk\coercion\array.d.ts(10,60): error TS1005: Build:',' expected

Tags: angular, typescript

I recently updated my application to Angular version 9.1.

I'm getting the following errors,

`@angular\cdk\coercion\array.d.ts(10,60): error TS1005: Build:',' expected.`

`@angular\cdk\coercion\array.d.ts(10,61): error TS1005: Build:',' expected.`

`@angular\cdk\coercion\array.d.ts(10,75): error TS1144: Build:'{' or ';' expected.`

`@angular\cdk\coercion\array.d.ts(10,77): error TS1011: Build: An element access expression should take an argument.`

**package.json**

```
"dependencies":{
"@angular/cdk":"9.2.4",
"@angular/core":"~9.1.12", 
"@angular/material":"9.2.4",
}
```

I'm absolutely clueless on how to fix this issue.

Am I using the right version of the libraries? What is wrong here? Is the error really in the above lines? Or Am I looking at
a completely different place to fix this issue?

Been trying to fix this for 2 days now. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: have you checked the [guide](https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=8.2-9.1)?

Comment: I did check, but the error that I'm facing isn't listed there. Thank you.

Comment: I think your versions are fine, I am actually running the same thing right now. Have you tried deleting the node modules folder and running npm install again

Comment: Yes, I tried that.

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes. I'll tell you the lines that I added to resolve this, in the morning.

Comment: @redevilliers what did yo do to solve rthis?